# How to display font that is related to a rectangle position using classes?

Tags: python, class, methods, fonts, pygame

I am struggling to rewrite a piece of -working code- I wrote in a more object oriented way and don't know how to attach Fonts (showing the position) to the 3 moving rects. In other words when I move those rects I want the number with their position to be attached to each of them.
Any suggestions to improve this code are also highly recommended.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
SCREEN = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
pg.font.init()

class Rectangle(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height, x , y):

        super().__init__()

        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.image = pg.Surface((width, 3*140 + height),pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        for z in range(0, 3 * 140, 140):
            pg.draw.rect(self.image, color, (0, z, self.width, self.height))

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        return int(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += event.rel[1]

    def rect_y(self):
        return self.rect.y

class Font(Rectangle):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height, x , y):
        super().__init__( color, width, height, x , y)

        self.font_a = pg.font.Font(None, 20)
        self.text = self.font_a.render(str(abs(int(object1.rect_y()))), True, (0,0,0))
        self.text_rect = self.text.get_rect()
        self.text_rect.y = Rectangle.rect_y(self)

object1 = Rectangle((50,100,100), 30, 100, 110 , 120)
selected1 = False
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if object1.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                selected1 = True

        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            selected1 = False

        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            if selected1:
                object1.update()

    SCREEN.fill(WHITE)

    font1 = Font((50,100,100), 30, 100, 110 , 120)
    SCREEN.blit(font1.text, font1.rect)

    object1.draw(SCREEN)
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: BTW, should the three rectangles always move together or should the user be able to move them separately as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add the `Font` objects (I renamed the class as `Label`) as attributes to the `Rectangle` instances. If you need multiple labels you can put them into a list. I gave the `Rectangle` a `handle_event` method to which I pass the `MOUSEMOTION` events to update its `self.rect`, then the rectangle passes the event to its labels, so that they can update their positions.

To store the sprite instances, you can use a `pygame.sprite.Group` (`all_sprites` in the example) which allows you to update all contained sprites by calling `all_sprites.update()` and `all_sprites.draw(SCREEN)`. `all_sprites.update()` is actually useless in this case, because the sprites don't have `update` methods (I just wanted to show you how it should be called in the main loop).

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
SCREEN = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
FONT_A = pg.font.Font(None, 20)
clock = pg.time.Clock()


class Rectangle(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height, x, y, all_sprites):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = color
        self.image = pg.Surface((width, 3*140 + height), pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        # If you need multiple labels, you can put them into a list.
        # You could also create and add them in the for loop below.
        self.labels = [Label(self.rect.right+3, self.rect.top, (0,0,0)),
                       Label(self.rect.right+3, self.rect.top+140, (0,0,0))]
        all_sprites.add(self.labels)

        for z in range(0, 3*140, 140):
            pg.draw.rect(self.image, color, (0, z, width, height))

    def handle_event(self, event):
        self.rect.y += event.rel[1]
        # Pass the event to the labels, so that they can handle it themselves.
        for label in self.labels:
            label.handle_event(event)


class Label(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = color
        self.image = FONT_A.render(str(abs(y)), True, self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

    def handle_event(self, event):
        self.rect.y += event.rel[1]
        self.image = FONT_A.render(str(abs(self.rect.y)), True, self.color)


def main():
    # Create a sprite group which will contain all sprite instances.
    # To update and draw the sprites you can just call its .update and .draw
    # methods.
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    # Pass the group to the Rectangle, because we need to add the labels.
    object1 = Rectangle((50,100,100), 30, 100, 110, 120, all_sprites)
    all_sprites.add(object1)

    selected1 = False
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if object1.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    selected1 = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                selected1 = False
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                if selected1:
                    # Pass the event to the object's handle_event method,
                    # where it uses it to update its rect and labels.
                    object1.handle_event(event)

        all_sprites.update()

        SCREEN.fill(WHITE)
        all_sprites.draw(SCREEN)

        pg.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

---

Addendum: If all labels should show the same value (the top position of the rects in this case), you can pass this value to the label instances and add it as an attribute. Then update it in the `handle_event` method as well and use it to render the font surface.

```
class Rectangle(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height, x, y, all_sprites):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = color
        self.image = pg.Surface((width, 3*140 + height), pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        # Pass another argument (the `value`) to the labels.
        self.labels = [Label(self.rect.right+3, self.rect.top, self.rect.top, (0,0,0)),
                       Label(self.rect.right+3, self.rect.top+140, self.rect.top, (0,0,0))]
        all_sprites.add(self.labels)

        for z in range(0, 3*140, 140):
            pg.draw.rect(self.image, color, (0, z, width, height))

    def handle_event(self, event):
        self.rect.y += event.rel[1]
        for label in self.labels:
            label.handle_event(event)


class Label(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, value, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = value
        self.color = color
        self.image = FONT_A.render(str(abs(self.value)), True, self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

    def handle_event(self, event):
        # Update the self.value as well and use it to render the new font surface.
        self.value += event.rel[1]
        self.rect.y += event.rel[1]
        self.image = FONT_A.render(str(abs(self.value)), True, self.color)
```

Comment: Wow, this is advanced solution I'd never figure out it myself. Yes the three rectangles should always move together and also each should display the same value can you advice how to do it with your method? Thanks a ton.

Comment: You mean the labels should all display the top position of the rectangle object? Do you actually need multiple labels or just one?

Comment: Yes the labels should all display the top position of the rectangle object. Multiple labels with the same value (of say first rect from the top).

Comment: I think the simplest solution would be to pass the top position to the labels during the instantiation, store it as an attribute (for example as `self.value`) and then update it as well in the `handle_event` method.

Comment: I stuck with this. Really can't make it work that is to have control over value of label and place where it should be blit using class...

Comment: Great, to give you idea what I want I've attached this short program but it works correctly only if you move all three rects, that is it entails the need for many different states, that's why I think I need classes.
https://uploadfiles.io/n394c

Comment: I've already added the new example. There's another alternative: You can pass the `self.rect` of the `Rectangle` class to the labels and then just use the `rect.top` to render the text surface.

Comment: BTW, if you have to upload code, I prefer websites like https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Yes it works, as it should, but there are many operation I will need to perform on font so I hope I could use further your method. Thanks again.